# swapping byrow for vector without converting to matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix that I'm storing as a vector for speed & memory considerations. I want to essentially swap from 'byrow=FALSE' to 'byrow=TRUE' without actually converting it to a matrix (again, for speed and memory considerations, the data could potentially be very large).

It's trivial to do going through a call to `matrix`, e.g. if I have a 2x3 matrix,

```
> a <- 1:6
> a
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> as.vector(matrix(a, nrow=2, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

I think I could come up with a manual solution involving pulling out every ith entry and reordering, etc, etc, but was hoping there might be a more straightforward solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: how slow is `dim(a) <- c(3,2); c(t(a))` ?

Comment: In R a matrix *is* a vector. It just has dimension attributes.

Comment: to follow up on my comment: I don't think you're going to do a lot better than the built-in `t()` function for transposition, and as @SimonO101 comments (and my example shows) there's not really any computation involved in converting to a matrix. Are you sure you're actually saving anything (time or memory) by storing as a vector?